# Am I right proving closed set is measurable if $\mu^*$ is a metric outer measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose $(X,d)$ is the metric space and $(X,S,\mu^*)$, where $\mu^*$ is a metric outer measure defined on a $\sigma$ ring $S$ of $X$ which includes all the open sets and closed sets.

I need to show that $\forall F \in S, \mu^*(F) \geq \mu^*(F \cap C)+\mu^*(F-C)$ where $C$ is a closed set. (since the $\leq$ part is trivial)

Define $C_\frac{1}{n}=\{x \in X|d(x,C) < \frac{1}{n}\}$ (It is an open set)

$\mu^*(F\cap C)+\mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n})=\mu^*((F\cap C)\cup(F-C_\frac{1}{n}))$ (By the definition of metric outer measure)

Since $\mu^*((F\cap C)\cup(F-C_\frac{1}{n}))\leq \mu^*(F)$(monotonicity), we have $\mu^*(F\cap C)+\mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n}) \leq \mu^*(F)$.  (Let $\mu^*(F) < \infty$)

So I need to show $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n})=\mu^*(F-C)$

$F-C=\{x\in F|d(x,C)>0\}$ (By the property of closed set)

$F-C_\frac{1}{n}=\{x\in F|d(x,C)\geq \frac{1}{n}\}$

Let $B=\{x\in F| 0 < d(x,C) <\frac{1}{n}\}=\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}\{x\in F| \frac{1}{k+1} \leq d(x,C) <\frac{1}{k}\}=\cup_{k=n}^{\infty}B_k$

So we have $F-C=(F-C_\frac{1}{n}) \cup B$

Obviously $\mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n}) \leq\mu^*( F-C)$ and so $\lim\limits_{n \to\infty} \mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n}) \leq \mu^*(F-C)$.

**The inverse part is hard for me.** By countable additivity, we have $\mu^*(F-C) \leq \mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n})+\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_k)$

$$\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_k)=\lim\limits_{s \to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{s}\mu^*(B_k)=\lim\limits_{s \to\infty}(\sum_{odds}\mu^*(B_i)+\sum_{even}\mu^*(B_i))=\lim\limits_{s \to\infty}(\mu^*(\cup(odds))+\mu^*(\cup(even)))$$

since $\mu^*(\cup(odds))+\mu^*(\cup(even)) \leq 2\mu^*(F)$, the series is convergent.

Since $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_k)=\sum_{k=n}^{s}\mu^*(B_k)+\sum_{k=s+1}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_k)$

We have $\lim\limits_{s \to\infty}\sum_{k=s+1}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_k)=0$

So $\mu^*(F-C) \leq \lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n})+\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\mu^*(B_k)=\lim\limits_{n \to\infty}\mu^*(F-C_\frac{1}{n})$